# SilverStripe 3.0 upgrade to 3.1 failure with Composer

Tags: composer-php, silverstripe

I've never upgraded a SilverStripe project before, so forgive me if I'm missing anything obvious.

I want to upgrade this 3.0.5 SilverStripe site I have running locally to the latest version (which is 3.1.6 or something similar). I updated my composer.json file (which is located within the project in [project name]/cms/composer.json) to look as such:

```
{
"name": "silverstripe/cms",
"type": "silverstripe-module",
"description": "The SilverStripe Content Management System",
"homepage": "http://silverstripe.org",
"license": "BSD-3-Clause",
"keywords": ["silverstripe", "cms"],
"authors": [
    {
        "name": "SilverStripe",
        "homepage": "http://silverstripe.com"
    },
    {
        "name": "The SilverStripe Community",
        "homepage": "http://silverstripe.org"
    }
],
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.2",
    "composer/installers": "*",
    "silverstripe/cms": "3.1.*",
    "silverstripe/framework": "3.1.*"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": ["tests/behat/"]
}
```

}

I also updated composer itself as I was prompted to do so in the terminal.

I went to the where the composer.json file is located, ran composer update in the terminal and got this error:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Can only install one of: silverstripe/cms[3.1.0, dev-master].
    - Can only install one of: silverstripe/cms[3.1.1, dev-master].
    - Can only install one of: silverstripe/cms[3.1.10, dev-master].
    - Can only install one of: silverstripe/cms[3.1.11, dev-master].
    - Can only install one of: silverstripe/cms[3.1.12, dev-master].
    - Can only install one of: silverstripe/cms[3.1.13, dev-master].
    - Can only install one of: silverstripe/cms[3.1.14, dev-master].
    - Can only install one of: silverstripe/cms[3.1.15, dev-master].
    - Can only install one of: silverstripe/cms[3.1.2, dev-master].
    - Can only install one of: silverstripe/cms[3.1.3, dev-master].
    - Can only install one of: silverstripe/cms[3.1.4, dev-master].
    - Can only install one of: silverstripe/cms[3.1.5, dev-master].
    - Can only install one of: silverstripe/cms[3.1.6, dev-master].
    - Can only install one of: silverstripe/cms[3.1.7, dev-master].
    - Can only install one of: silverstripe/cms[3.1.8, dev-master].
    - Can only install one of: silverstripe/cms[3.1.9, dev-master].
    - Installation request for silverstripe/cms dev-master -> satisfiable by silverstripe/cms[dev-master].
    - Installation request for silverstripe/cms 3.1.* -> satisfiable by silverstripe/cms[3.1.0, 3.1.1, 3.1.10, 3.1.11, 3.1.12, 3.1.13, 3.1.14, 3.1.15, 3.1.2, 3.1.3, 3.1.4, 3.1.5, 3.1.6, 3.1.7, 3.1.8, 3.1.9].
```

Do I need to be specific as to which version of SilverStripe I need to update to? I didn't see a composer.lock file in the project, but I did remove a line in web.config that was calling to one:

```
<add segment="composer.lock" />
```

Should the composer.json file be located elsewhere in the project (as opposed to [project name]/cms)?

UPDATE: With composer installed in the root directory and a composure.json file located there, I still get errors when trying to upgrade the site to SilverStripe 3.1:

```
composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Updating composer/installers dev-master (v1.0.2 => e420b53)



  [RuntimeException]
  The .git directory is missing from /Projects/[project name]/vendor/composer/installers, see https://getcomposer.org/commit-deps for more information



update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--with-dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [packages1] ... [packagesN]


 ~/Projects/[project name] $ php composer.phar install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Updating silverstripe/framework (3.0.x-dev 29de643 => 3.1.x-dev 92970f8)



  [RuntimeException]
  The .git directory is missing from framework/, see https://getcomposer.org/commit-deps for more information



install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [packages1] ... [packagesN]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn’t be editing cms/composer.json, you should be editing the composer.json at the root of your project (if there is one present - there may not be a composer.json if the previous developer didn't install with composer).

Comment: Can I just install composer into the root of the project?

Comment: @SaraDeJaneiro you can create a composer.json at the root level if there isn’t one there already, yes.

Comment: Ok, I will try that...I don't know what the previous dev did. I can't ask, either, since he is not working here anymore.

Comment: @SaraDeJaneiro just be careful when upgrading to SS 3.1 as the jump from 3.0 to 3.1 is not SemVer compliant (the project has adopted SemVer from 3.2 onwards). You will probably have to make some manual updates to your codebase as a result of changes to the API between those versions. Check out https://github.com/sunnysideup/silverstripe-upgrade_silverstripe for a tool that can help with the process.

Comment: I have composer installed in the root directory now, and I have a composer.json file. But I keep getting errors. I updated my post to include these

Comment: Ok, I think I got it working and the site appears upgraded.